# How to determine what part of an AJAX application is slowing things down?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, performance, database-performance

I'm writing my first AJAX driven website and some parts of it are kind of slow. For example, I'll click a button to change the page, and it might take three seconds for the new page to appear.

Chrome developer tools shows the network activity for the page being changed as follows:

> DNS Lookup     ​1 ms
>
> Connecting     ​45 ms
>
> SSL    ​21 ms
>
> Sending    ​0
>
> Waiting    ​1.89 s
>
> Receiving  ​73 ms

The size of the above request was 49.1 KB.

Clearly the "Waiting" time is where the slowdown is occurring. My question is, what is causing this "waiting" time? Is it something to do with the jQuery AJAX request, or is it because the MySQL database is slow, or something in a PHP file causing a delay?

Without seeing my project and debugging it first-hand, you may not be able to answer that question. If that's the case, how should *I* go about determining which part of the application is slowing things down?

Comment: Clicking something that fetches an entire new page is not what you should ajax for. Things like that are better left to links (that's what they're for). Ajax gets little slivers of info/content that get injected into the current DOM

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - Changing the page was just an example. In my application, there is data being displayed in a spreadsheet-like format. When the user clicks a button, new data is fetched and displayed. This is where the slowdown is happening (among other places).

Comment: Ok, perhaps be a tad more specific, but on the whole, this question is just too broad. The bottleneck could be anything, from your JS code, the test environment, your server setup, the storage engine used, the size of the data... there's nothing really anyone can say with a 100% certainty, that will double your performance.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - `The bottleneck could be anything, from your JS code, the test environment, your server setup, the storage engine used, the size of the data...` Exactly, so what I'm asking is, how do I narrow it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Without seeing my project and debugging it first-hand, you may not be able to answer that question. If that's the case, how should I go about determining which part of the application is slowing things down?

That depends on your debug tools. At the most basic level, comment out parts of your server-side code and check how much the "waiting" time drops.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about profiling MySQL/PHP applications (in Django, you could use django-debug-toolbar), but Ajax queries are good candidates to cache in both DB and app output layers.

Consider using a cache system like memcached.